# Remove Cookies in Visual Studio WebTest

Tags: c#, load-testing, web-testing, visual-studio-test-runner

I want Remove Cookies of application in visual studio webtest 
how can i do it ?
this is one of my WebTestRequest

```
WebTestRequest request = new WebTestRequest(
  DataProvider.Data.OnlineServer + "/Auth/Login"
);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ExpectedResponseUrl = (DataProvider.Data.OnlineServer + "/");
request.Headers.Add(
  new WebTestRequestHeader(
    "Referer",
    DataProvider.Data.OnlineServer + "/Auth/Login"
  )
);    
FormPostHttpBody request2Body = new FormPostHttpBody();
request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("loginHash", loginHash);
request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("username", username);
request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("password", password);
request2Body.FormPostParameters.Add("otp", "");
request.Body = request2Body;
return request;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7dfefda3-14ea-4529-b541-79ef09ee130a/webtestcontextclear-not-clearing-cookies?forum=vstswebtest) you can clear the cookies by creating a new `CookieContainer` and assigning it to the web test context. Thus overwriting the unwanted (container of) cookies with a new empty container.

In a Coded web test the code would be:

```
this.Context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

In a plugin the code would be:

```
e.WebTest.Context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

Comment: thanks a lot AdrianHHH
I do it,but didn't work.when i debug it in visual studio Context.CookieContainer.Count at first is 2 then after this.Context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer() is 0

but it did'nt work and show captcha yet.when i monitor request in fiddler  the cookies did'nt remove

Comment: How to add Cookies to the request??

Comment: @PriyaPayyavula That looks like a new question. Have you properly searched for answers? If you cannot find and asnwer then consider writing a new question explaining in detail what you want to do.